# Check if string exists in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList with genres:

```
List<String> availableGenres = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Arcade", "Puzzle", "Racing", "Casual", 
      "Strategy", "Sport")
        );
```

I want to check if incoming string exists in this ArrayList. Okay, it's simple with contains, incoming "Sport":

```
if (availableGenres.contains(game.getGenre())){
    ...    
    this true   
}
```

But sometimes incoming String contains both of these values, like this: "Puzzle Arcade" and this method will return false, but it's actually true. How to deal with this case?

Comment: You have to split the incoming String, split and for each part check its presence in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is split the input using *whitespace* and then check if any of the values in the `ArrayList` contain any of the input value(s).

```
String input = "Puzzle Arcade";

boolean contains = Stream.of(input.split(" "))
    .anyMatch(availableGenres::contains);
```

It is worth noting that you could also use a Set of String instead of a List if the values are unique (include case-sensitive).

Comment: Or `anyMatch(availableGenres::contains)`.

Comment: Yeah, very well said, i'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly check which word matches in the user-given string

```
str = "Puzzle Arcade";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");

for each(String word : tokens){
  if (availableGenres.contains(word)){
    //mark which word was present if you want to
    //TRUE;
    }
}
```